# Why is norm map on ker of reduction of elliptic curve surjective?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, local-fields

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over local field $K$ of characteristic $0$. Let $F/K$ be quadratic extension.
Let $E_1$ be kennel of reduction. Let $N: E(F)\to E(K)$ by $P\to P+P^{\sigma}$($\sigma$ is a generator of $Gal(F/K)$).

Proposition 3 of the provided link(https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1981-264-01/S0002-9947-1981-0597871-8/S0002-9947-1981-0597871-8.pdf) claims that
$E_1(F)/N(E_1(K)$ is trivial group because $E_1(K)$ is uniquely divisible by 2 and $N・(inc)=[2]$.

However, I cannot understand why these two reasons conclusively show that $E_1(F)/N(E_1(K)$ is trivial group. Why does$E_1(F)/N(E_1(K)$ become obvious group?

In other words, why is norm map on ker of reduction of elliptic curve surjective ?

Comment: You missed the crucial hypothesis that the residual characteristic is ODD in Prop 3. Take a point $P$ in $E_1(K)$. Since the formal group is divisible by $2$, there is $Q$ in $E_1(K)$ such that $2Q=P$. Now $N(Q)=2Q=P$ and you are done.